# regular expression, match all text within two characters

Tags: php, regex

I need to ask because this takes me too much time to go over again and again every time needed, how to match this:

```
Tom Yorke(55555)
```

when given this:

```
CN=Tom Yorke(55555),OU=Admins,OU=London,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=london,DC=local
```

using php `preg_match()`

Answer (score 4):

> only want the first occurence of text within = and ,

Try this. `$result` will hold the match, or be `NULL` if there's not match

```
$data = "...";//original string
$pattern = '/=([^,]+)/';
$matches = [];
preg_match($pattern, $data, $matches);
$result = count($matches)? $matches[1]: null; // Tom Yorke(55555)
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/QRp3q)